# CSS – Header in display: table element – positioning issue

Tags: html, css

While creating a HTML layout, I noticed some strange positioning issue I was unable to solve.

Take the following HTML:

```
<div class="outer-wrap">
<div class="header">
    I am a Header
</div>
<div class="element">
    Hello world
</div>
```

And combine with this CSS code:

```
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.2/normalize.css";

html, body { height: 100%; }

.outer-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    background: grey;
}

.element {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: blue;
}

.header {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnpm6338/1/)

As you can see, I've set the wrapper to `display: table`, which enables me to vertically center any child element with setting `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle`.

Now when I try to add a header, strange things start to happen.

First, I have to declare `position: absolute` on the header, otherwise the header horizontally pushes away `.element`. I don't know why this happens, but I understand why this fix works: Because `position: absolute` takes things 'out of the flow'.

But if I take a look at the Fiddle, you'll notice a small gap on the left side which exposes the grey background color defined on `.outer-wrap`:

[image]

What is causing this gap & how to fix this?
Why do I have to use absolute positioning on the header to make it expand to the full container width?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I've added a screenshot how it looks in Safari 7 and Chrome 39 on OSX.

Comment: you are missing table-row

Comment: @wlin Could you please elaborate this a bit more?

Comment: I also had the same problem before, but was forgot, now seeing your question reminded me.+1

Answer (score 0):

The key reason causing that is you're not defining the table-cell div and would not be 100% wide and you see its shifting towards right seeing the gray border color which is the background of outer-wrap div. So, you need to define the `width:100%;` when you use `display:table-cell;` to make it display correctly.

Changed css:

```
.outer-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    background: grey;
}

.element {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;/*explicitly define width to be 100%*/
}

.header {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    z-index: 1;/*to make it display in front*/
}
```

[Fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnpm6338/3/)